# setValueAt for check box value in JTable Multiarray

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, checkbox, jtable

I am currently having an issue with setting values to Checkbox in JTable.
I need to store Boolean values per checkbox in rows of the table.
I can display default(false) checkbox, but once I click check box, I get an exception; java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0. 
I am not too familiar with multi arrays with Boolean and I cannot seem to figure out which part of my code is incorrect.

```
public static final int CHECKBOX= 0;
private final List<Data> datas;
private static boolean CHECKBOX_RENDERED[][] = new boolean[][]{};
private static Arrays array = null;

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (rowIndex >= this.datas.size()) {
        return null;
    }

    Data theData= this.datas.get(rowIndex);
    if (theData== null) {
        return null;
    }

    //Initialize the boolean field with table dimension
    CHECKBOX_RENDERED = new boolean[datas.size()][columnIndex];

    switch(columnIndex) {
    case CHECKBOX:
        array.fill(CHECKBOX_RENDERED[rowIndex], false);
        return false; //default
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column index");
    }
}


@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    if (column == CHECKBOX) {
        Data data= this.datas.get(row);
        if (data!= null && value instanceof Boolean) {

            if (CHECKBOX_RENDERED[row][column]) {
                CHECKBOX_RENDERED[row][column] = false;
            } else {
                CHECKBOX_RENDERED[row][column] = true;
            }

            fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: With camickr's answer, I was able to find other places to correct my code and it resolved the issue. 
I moved the line CHECKBOX_RENDERED = new boolean[datas.size()][columnIndex]; after the line where data is loaded.
I removed array field completely and return CHECKBOX_RENDERED[rowIndex][columnIndex]; in case CHECKBOX of the switch statement.

Comment: `...after the line where data is loaded.` - and that code was not even included with the question. That is why you have been asked to post a proper "MCVE/SSCCE" with every question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static boolean CHECKBOX_RENDERED[][] = new boolean[][]{};
```

You define a 2D array variable but you never actually define a size for the rows and columns of the array. So therefore the size of the array is (0, 0) and you can't add/change any data in the array.

Don't create you own table model.

The simplest solution is to just use the `DefaultTableModel`. It will manage the data for you. You just need to define the number of rows/columns you want in the table and it will manage the rest for you.

Or if you don't know how many rows data you need then you can use the `addRows(...)` method to dynamically add rows as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
but, I did define value to the field CHECKBOX_RENDERED = new boolean[datas.size()][columnIndex]; in getValueAt method.

Comment: My question is I filled the array variable
 array.fill(CHECKBOX_RENDERED[rowIndex], false);
and how can I reset the Boolean value in setValueAt method?

Comment: Where do you ever add items to the  "datas" List?  The size of the array needs to be defined when you create the class. When you add the logic to the getValueAt() method you will recreate the array every time the method is invoked!!! Add a System.out.println(...) statement to the getValueAt() to see how many times this method is invoked. Again, I suggest you just use the DefaultTableModel until you learn the basics of using a JTable.

Comment: Yes You have a good point.. I shouldn't define the value in getValueAt()..

Comment: @In-youngChoung, `You have a good point` - glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Definitely I will, but it hasn't entirely solved my problem.

Comment: @In-youngChoung It solved the problem for this stated question. This is not 20 questions. You take the time to understand the suggestion and make your own fixes. We are not here to debug every line of code. This is basic problem solving were you need to improve your debugging skills. Things like adding System.out.println(...) statements to the code to see what is happening. And the suggestion to use the DefaultTableModel will solve all your problems.

Comment: If you need practice creating your own custom table model, then start with the example from the Swing tutorial  on [Creating a TableModel]. The code you posted looks nothing like the basic example from the tutorial. There is no need for any processing logic in the getValueAt() or setValueAt() methods.